# np.savetxt - add one header to csv file

Tags: python, numpy, file

I want to add 1 header to the csv file but the header will be added to each row. [this is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxl8O.png)

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usQ0v.png)

```
IMG_DIR = 'path to the images'

for img in os.listdir(IMG_DIR):
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR,img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_array = (img_array.flatten())
img_array  = img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T
print(img_array)
with open('Data.csv', 'ab') as c:
np.savetxt(c, img_array , fmt='%d', delimiter=",", header=',', comments='')
```

Comment: `savetxt` does the same thing each time you call it.  The fact that the file already exits doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not repeatedly open the file inside the loop. Open it outside the loop and add header prior to loop once:

```
IMG_DIR = 'path to the images'

with open('Data.csv', 'ab') as c:
  c.write(b'\n')
  for img in os.listdir(IMG_DIR):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_DIR,img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img_array = (img_array.flatten())
    img_array  = img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T
    print(img_array)
    np.savetxt(c, img_array , fmt='%d', delimiter=",", comments='')
```

Also, `img_array.reshape(-1, 1).T` is the same as `img_array.reshape(1, -1)` and you do not need to both flatten and reshape. Just reshape is fine.

Comment: can you help me to add name to each column, example Column1 , Column2, ........, Column1280